# Pi camera Openelec

Tags: camera, raspicam, kodi, openelec

I want to know if there is an add-on to launch the script for the Raspberry Pi camera on Openelec Kodi for the Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: I would suggest SSH'ing into the Pi and try running a command to enable to camera, but I can't seem to find such a command. You might then be able to use all of the normal camera commands that can be run in the terminal. I've definitely not heard of any add-ons that can utilize the camera, but there might be one out there.

Comment: I have thought about an add-on Surveillance Room, its goes very well with Foscam camera or ip camera. I tried with the ip address of my pi and it can't open my pi camera, there is a way to launch it from this add-on? @DarthVader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.

From OpenELEC's main menu select the following:

- System
- Settings
- Add-ons
- Install from repository
- OpenELEC Add-ons (official)
- Add-on repository
- OpenELEC Add-ons (unofficial)

This should install the unofficial repo. Go back two screens to the main `Install from repository` screen, where you should see the new option `OpenELEC Add-ons (unofficial)`. From that screen select:

- OpenELEC Add-ons (unofficial)
- Program add-ons
- picamera
- Install

That's described as 'A python and shell interface for the Raspberry Pi camera module', and should get you up and running. At this point you can log in to your OpenELEC instance over SSH and run both `raspistill` and `raspivid` from the terminal.

In the event that you need to launch `raspistill` or `raspivid` from the OpenELEC interface, rather than from an SSH session, you can use the [Advanced Launcher](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Advanced_Launcher) add-on. It's worth noting that Advanced Launcher is usually used with game emulators, so there are a couple of weird/irrelevant options in there.

There's a good walkthrough of two different approaches to installing the launcher add-on [here at misapuntesde.com](http://misapuntesde.com/post.php?id=502). I've just tested the shorter approach and everything went fine. You'll need an SSH connection to get the necessary files.

> Log into SSH and type:
>
> ```
> wget http://misapuntesde.com/res/AdvLauncher_uLySeSS.zip 
> unzip AdvLauncher_uLySeSS.zip -d / 
> rm AdvLauncher_uLySeSS.zip 
> killall -9 kodi.bin
> ```

The final command will reboot the Pi. When it's restarted, from the main menu:

- Programs
- Advanced Launcher
- Right click/long press on Default
- Add New Launcher
- Standalone launcher (normal executable)
- Root filesystem
- storage
- .kodi
- addons
- python.picamera
- bin
- raspivid

You should get a dialog with the title `Application arguments`. In the dialog box type:

```
-t 10000
```

The command `raspivid -t 10000` should [produce a live preview of the camera for 10 seconds](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/RaspiCam-Documentation.pdf).

- In the next dialog box, give your launcher a name (I stuck with raspivid).
- The `Select the platform` dialog is irrelevant - select `3DO`.
- (Thumbnails path dialog) OK
- (Fanarts path dialog) OK

You should now see the list of all available launchers, including the new `raspivid` entry. Running that displays a full screen preview feed from the Pi camera for 10 seconds, then exits. You can tweak the settings used by changing the application arguments per the [RaspiCam documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/RaspiCam-Documentation.pdf).

Comment: When i try to open it i receive this information : ' This is a console-only addon'. Some other hints to solve this issue?

Comment: @Amiga500 I've updated with some instructions for launching things from the Kodi interface rather than SSH.